# How can time-evolution lead a Nèel-ordered state to an entangled state?

Tags: quantum-information, quantum-entanglement, hamiltonian, time-evolution

I am working with a system governed by the Following Hamiltonian:

H = $\sum_{i<j} J_{ij}(\sigma_i^+ \sigma_j^- + \sigma_i^- \sigma_j^+) + B\sum_j\sigma_j^z$

The Time evolution is:

$|\psi(t)\rangle = exp(-iHt)|\psi(0)\rangle$

Where the system is initialized to a Nèel-ordered state which, for 10-qubits, it reads $|\psi(0)\rangle = |1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0\rangle$.

I read in a papaer that "the intecration initially gives rise to entanglement among neighbouring qubits, which then spreads over the entire quantum register".

I am wondering how can this system evolve to a highly entangled state since the initial state $|\psi(0)\rangle$ is a `1 x 1024`array with only one non-zero entry. Everytime I multiply the exponential of the Hamiltonian to this initial state I am multiplying just a bunch of zeros and one non zero entry which hapens to be of value 1. How can this give rise to entanglement? I thought of

1. Single-qubit rotations. Maybe applying rotations around different axis to individual qubits  can introduce superposition and mix the spin orientations leading to entanglement. Does it make sense? I think I will explore it in this way but I am not sure.
2. Two-qubit interactions. Maybe apply controlled operations, such as controlled-NOT gates, between pairs of qubits.

The time evolution was suggested as a 'natural' way to lead to entanglement but, as I argued above, I don't see how can it be possible just with time evolution.

Comment: Time evolution for a finite time amounts to multiplication with a unitary matrix. This can easily change the number of zeros and ones in the vector, as vector-matrix multiplication produces linear combinations of the entries of the vector.